# May I split List<int> date the put into for loop?

Tags: flutter

May I split List date the put into for loop or use switch case??

this is my code

```
getFeature() async {
    final docSnapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('Campsite')
        .doc(widget.CamperSiteID)
        .get();
    final CamperSiteSummary =
        List<int>.from(docSnapshot.data()?['CamperSiteSummary'] ?? []);
    //this._CamperSiteSummary.addAll(CamperSiteSummary);

    setState(() {
      _CamperSiteSummary = CamperSiteSummary;
      print(_CamperSiteSummary);
    });
  }
```

I'd print the data

```
flutter: [2, 3, 5, 6, 10, 13, 14, 19, 29, 37]
```

So, May I split _CamperSiteSummary data then put into loop or use switch case??

I hope it's can realize this, this is my android(JAVA) screen.

[image]

So, I need to split the data then how could used loop way to show image?

this is my android-jave code

```
 public void showChips(ChipGroup chipGroup, List<Integer> chipList) {
        HashMap<Integer, Integer> campSiteMap = new HashMap<>();

        campSiteMap.put(1, R.id.chip1);
        campSiteMap.put(2, R.id.chip2);
        campSiteMap.put(3, R.id.chip3);
        campSiteMap.put(4, R.id.chip4);
        campSiteMap.put(5, R.id.chip5);
...
...
...
campSiteMap.put(37, R.id.chip37);
        campSiteMap.put(38, R.id.chip38);
        campSiteMap.put(39, R.id.chip39);
        try {
            for (Integer id : chipList){
                chipGroup.findViewById(campSiteMap.get(id)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: get no id
        }

    }
```

How can modity fluute code?

Comment: I'm not sure what are you trying to do with that data, can you be more specific?

Comment: @mohamed.oussous Because each number has its own pattern, I need to disassemble it and give them the pattern positions respectively

Or that I don't have to break them down? Can you make them correspond to their own patterns?

Comment: you can access each int inside a list by : CamperSiteSummary.forEach((element) { print(element); });

Comment: @mohamed.oussous thx, bro, Then how can I combine all the patterns? If there is matching information

Comment: if you're trying to link that int with java code try MethodChannel in Flutter

Comment: @mohamed.oussous No, I don;t link java code. I need to use flutter code, but I don't know how can realize like picture that.